# Include convert multiple rows into one with comma as separator in main view Sql

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Tables diagram

[image]

I had two tables main and sub table.
I need to include all users for each service in one comma delimited string

```
SELECT        SrvID, SrvTitle, SrvStatus, '' AS SrvUsersText
FROM          ServicesData
```

To be result like this

[image]

Comment: Use: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Luuk i need to use it inside main table sql

Comment: Can you share some simple data and the expected output as text not images, so it can be easy for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Luuk commented, for getting list as comma separated you need to use `STRING_AGG` function like this:

```sql
SELECT        SrvID, SrvTitle, SrvStatus, 
STRING_AGG(concat(su.LineUserId,'-',su.LineUserName), ',') AS SrvUsersText
FROM          ServicesData
Join ServiceUsers su on <conditions>
group by SrvID, SrvTitle, SrvStatus
```

Comment: <conditions> Do you mean 
Join ServiceUsers su on ServicesData.SrvID

Comment: @AhmedAboelez Yes you got it